# How do you convert observable of array to array or iterate through observable of array to get a value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

So I want to get an `id` from a returned observable object to use it for another service call.

```
export class CustomerComponent{
  current: Customer;
  orders: Observable<Order[]>;
  orderitems: Observable<OrderItem[]>;
  o: Order[]= [];
  orderid: number;
    
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private vs: AccountverificationService,
    private os:OrderService, 
    private ois:OrderItemService) 
  {
    this.vs.current.subscribe(x=>this.current=x);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orders = this.os.getOrders(this.current.id).pipe(
      map((orderz:Order[]) => this.o = orderz)
    );
        
    this.o.forEach((or: Order) => {
      this.orderid = or.id;
    })
    this.orderitems = this.ois.getOrderItems(this.orderid);  
  }
}
```

What I am doing here is that I am calling get all orders service (get them by customer id).
And then for each order, I want to take its order id to call get order items service.
I am thinking of two options:

1. Directly loop through the `Observable<Order[]>` and extract orderid.
2. Transform `Observable<Order[]>` to array `Order[]` and loop over the array to get orderid

However, in my code I tried the second option.

I used `.pipe(map`

But it is not working, orderid is still undefined.
Even orders is undefined!

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Tried this today, still not working !!! help:(

```
this.orders = this.os.getOrders(this.current.id).pipe(
  tap(orderz => {
    orderz.forEach((or :Order)=> {
      this.orderid = or.id;
    });
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what final output you're looking for. But in general:

- Use `switchMap` to map to an Observable.
- Use `forkJoin` to execute multiple completing observables in parallel.

To get a value from any Observable you have to subscribe.

```ts
orders$: Observable<{ orderId: string, orderItems: any[] }>;

ngOnInit() {
  this orders$ = this.os.getOrders(this.current.id).pipe(
    switchMap((orderz:Order[]) => forkJoin(
      // map every order to an observable that emits your required data for that order
      orderz.map(o => this.ois.getOrderItems(o.id).pipe(
        // e.g. an object containing the order id and the order items for this id
        map(orderItems => ({ orderId: o.id, orderItems }))
      ))
    ))
  )
}
```

```html
<ng-content *ngIf="orders$ | async as orders">
  <div *ngFor="let order of orders">
    {{ order | json }}
  </div>
</ng-content>
```

Comment: How can I use the values of value to render them in html?

Comment: @nadabtadine It's best to use the AsyncPipe in your html template. This is basic Angular. Consider working through the [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/start) to learn the basics.